# HTML & CSS styling for Pricelist Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is possibly an easy one, but im not sure how to approach it;

I'm building a Bootstrap Responsive website, which needs to have a pricelist ~ the style which you'd see on a Takeaway menu flyer;
Its being placed in a container (so its not full width), but ideally it should look something like this on a desktop screen:

short.................................................. $50
Medium.............................................. $75
Long................................................... $100

then on a tablet or mobile screen, the amount of dots should be reduced, so it looks something like this;

short...... $50
Medium...$75
Long...... $100

Any suggestions on the best way to approach this?  And obviously i want the right hand side dollar signs to all line up.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about not posting a code snippet with my question;

Anyway, I found my own answer - I just hadn't been searching Google with the right query;

This was one of many solutions I found (and ended up using);
[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/cqWFx/329/)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="left">Name:</div>
<div class="right">Engineer</div>
<div class="dotted"></div>
<div class="left">Factory location:</div>
<div class="right">not invoice address</div>
<div class="dotted"></div>
```

CSS Code:

```
div{
        height:1em;
    }
    .left,.right{
        padding:1px 0.5em;
        background:#fff;
        float:right;
    }
    .left{
        float:left;
        clear:both;
    }

.dotted{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
```